# How to compare a list of dict with list of tuples in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a `list` of `dict` as below:

```
objList =   [{
            'Name': 'keyboard',
            'objectId': [0, 1],
            'StartTime': '2022-01-10T13:18:17.098119',
            'IsCompleted': False,
            'MetaData': [{
                'Count': 2
            }]
        }, {
            'Name': 'smallObjects',
            'objectId': [2, 3],
            'StartTime': '2022-01-10T13:18:33.950507',
            'IsCompleted': False,
            'MetaData': [{
                'Count': 2
            }]
        }]
```

and list of tuples:

```
objectsCounter = [('keyboard', 2), ('smallObjects', 4)]
```

I have to write a python code where I have to checkif `MetaData` from `dict` (for both keyboard & smallObjects) in `objList` if greater than or equal to the count in `objectsCounter`. If yes, then I have to set `IsCompleted` to `True` otherwise `False`. For this I have written below code and its working fine

```
for obj1 in objList:
    for obj2 in objectsCounter:
        if obj2[0] == obj1['Name']:
            if obj2[1] >= obj1['MetaData'][0]['Count']:
                obj1['IsCompleted'] = True
                
            break
```

But because I am using lot of `for` and `if`, I feel there must be a better way to do this comparison. Can anyone help me in optimizing the above code or does above code looks fine. Thanks

Comment: It would be better if you used `objectsCounter = {'keyboard': 2, 'smallObjects': 4}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution works pretty well, here is another way of doing it.  Turn your `objectsCounter` into a Dictionary and then loop through only one list

```
o=dict(objectsCounter )

for i in objList:
  #Matching your code
  i['IsCompleted']= o[i['Name']] >= i['MetaData'][0]['Count']
```

You will only loop through the items you need, ie those in `objList`.  You also don't need `if` when you just set the value for `isCompleted` to the logical comparison.

To match the description not code just change the operator

```
      i['IsCompleted']= o[i['Name']] <= i['MetaData'][0]['Count']
```

Comment: I have ran your code but not sure why, for `smallObjects` how come `IsCompleted` is True?

Comment: @SAndrew I reread your post, the problem you describe is little different than your code.  Code you listed shows True for `smallObjects` and you mentioned it works.  Which should it be?  In your code it's `true` `if obj2[1] >= obj1['MetaData'][0]['Count']` with `obj2` being `objectsCounter`